# Log_path_is_undefined and log_file_is_undefined

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I'm updating Spring boot version from 2.5 to 2.6 and I encounter an issue with Logback.
Here's the snippet of my application.properties file:

```
logging.file=abc.log
logging.path=.
```

And a part of my logback-spring.xml

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH:-.}/${LOG_FILE}.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH:-.}/${LOG_FILE}-%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <!-- Only allow a file to get to ~10MB -->
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %-5level [%-35.35logger{30}] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

I'm getting the error:

```
2022-10-07 22:51:08,903 INFO  [o.h.v.internal.util.Version        ] HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.22.Final
2022-10-07 22:51:09,241 INFO  [o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassParser   ] Properties location [classpath:application.properties] not resolvable: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2022-10-07 22:51:10,158 WARN  [.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
```

I also get a file named: log_file_is_undefined.log

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging):

> **${LOG_FILE}**: Whether **logging.file.name** was set in Boot’s external configuration.
>
> **${LOG_PATH}**: Whether **logging.file.path** (representing a directory for log files to live in) was set in Boot’s external configuration.

So use:

```
logging.file.name=abc.log
logging.file.path=.
```

Comment: @Khushboo if this helped, please accept my answer so that this question can be closed.

Comment: Thanks Dirk! I didn't knew I had to accept it. Taken a note.